# Flutter Live Streaming app using webcam not working and crash

Tags: flutter, webrtc, live-streaming, rtcpeerconnection, videosdk.live

I am using videosdk to build my live streaming app, I follow the instruction of quick start guide to build the interactive live streaming [videosdk tutorial link](https://docs.videosdk.live/flutter/guide/video-and-audio-calling-api-sdk/quick-start-ils), when I clicked create meeting, if I using emulated front cam in android studio, everything works fine, but if I change to real webcam, I click the create meeting button, it will crash or back to home screen.

video sdk error

[image]

I try to change the device, but it still didn't work, and research through the website, but the videosdk community don't have so much information

Comment: maybe um not sure though, u can access webcam if u degug ur app on futter web, u can't do dat with phn cz it has default system. try it on **real devices

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JBJason Yeah, I tried on the real devices, it actually worked, I get the answer from the assistant of the videosdk community. Thanks man